# Nvidia-smi does not display any processes

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm working on a small case with Tensorflow.
Installed version :tensorflow (version 1.13.1), tensorflow-gpu==1.13.1, cuda10.0, cudnn7.4, windows10, GPU:740M, compatibility：3.5.

The problem when I run the code to check if GPU is used to speed up the process, `nvidia-smi` , no running processes found.

Here is part of my code:

```
class DQN():
    # DQN Agent
    def __init__(self, env):
        self.replay_buffer = deque()
        self.time_step = 0
        self.epsilon = INITIAL_EPSILON
        self.state_dim = env.observation_space.shape[0]  
        self.action_dim = env.action_space.n            

        # Init session
        import os
        os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]= "0,1,2"
        config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True, allow_soft_placement=True,device_count = {'GPU': 3} )
        config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
        config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.8
        self.session = tf.InteractiveSession(config = config)
        self.create_Q_network()
        self.create_training_method()
        self.session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        # loading networks
        self.saver = tf.train.Saver()
        global summary_writer
        summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('~/car_logs',graph=self.session.graph)
```

and I use `log_device_placement`to record the state of device, I can get the result. It seems GPU is successfully used in this process from the  log shown?
[image]

Since I use `self.session = tf.InteractiveSession(config = config)`, I guess all the operation will be run in this session. But why even the process of GPU won't show by nvidia-smi?

I constantly call the ``nvidia -smi``` while the program running, but get the same result. I know the memory usage may not shown in wdmm mode, but the process is supposed to be there I guess.
[image]

How should I check this as I wish if it's successfully run on my GPU.

Thanks in advace!

Answer (score 0):

A shim driver allows in-docker nvidia-smi showing correct process list without modify anything.

see:https://github.com/matpool/mpu

Comment: Please add at least a small example snippet to your answer. Links can change.